# Create multiple pages in a richtextbox in winforms [c#]

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

I'm making a simple text editor, and I was wondering if there is a way to create word alike pages. I did some searching, but I didn't found something usefull. Does someone knows if and how this is possible?

thanks in advance.

if someone wants to download it:
http://omegapps.nl/Content/Synonym/Synonym.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard RichTextBox control is very basic. If You need extended functionality, try out some other frameworks controls like Telerik and/or DevExpress.

[DevExpress RichTextEdit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8723eaa1-3e0f-4cd7-a44e-f92e168fe367)

[Telerik RichTextEditor](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/richtexteditor/overview)